# No gain from Cython on function definition

Tags: python, cython

I need to use a shifting function in a program several times and I would like to pass my routine to Cython. The function takes an arbitrary complex array defined over some grid, a shift value over the grid and the maximum value of the grid. Thus, if I have y(w) as my initial array with w being the grid, we have F( f(w) ) = f( w + shift ). We also assume that f( w -> +/- \infty) = 0. Note that the returned array belongs to the original grid "w_grid"

The Python code of the routine is like this:

```
def shift_array( the_array, w_grid, shift_value, w_max ):
    if ( abs( shift_value ) > w_max  ): 
        zeros_res = np.zeros( len(the_array), dtype = np.complex128 )
        return  zeros_res
    else:        
        if ( shift_value != 0.0 ):
            result         = np.zeros( len(the_array), dtype = np.complex128 )
            total_elements = len( the_array )                      
          
            if shift_value > 0:                
                dist_vec = min( w_grid + shift_value ) 
                v        = np.abs( w_grid - dist_vec  ) 
                index    = np.argwhere( v == v.min() )[0][0] 
                result   = np.roll( the_array, index )
                result[0:index] = 0                 
            else:
                dist_vec = max( w_grid + shift_value ) 
                v        = np.abs( w_grid - dist_vec  ) 
                index    = total_elements - np.argwhere( v == v.min() )[0][0] 
                result   = np.roll( the_array, -index )
                result[-index:] = 0                                                   
            return  result                
        else: return the_array
```

Now, writing the Cython version of the routine:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
import scipy
from libcpp cimport bool
from time import time

os_platform = sys.platform

cdef long double PI  = 3.141592653589793238462
i_unit               = np.complex( 0.0, 1.0 )
DTYPE                = np.complex128
INT_TYPE             = np.int8
FLOAT_TYPE           = np.float64

ctypedef np.complex128_t DTYPE_t
ctypedef np.int8_t INT_TYPE_t
ctypedef np.float64_t FLOAT_TYPE_t
    
#######################################################
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def shift_array_cython( np.ndarray[ DTYPE_t, ndim=1 ] the_array, 
                          np.ndarray[ FLOAT_TYPE_t, ndim=1 ] w_grid, 
                          FLOAT_TYPE_t shift_value,
                          FLOAT_TYPE_t w_max ):
    
    cdef Py_ssize_t total_elements = len(the_array)
    cdef Py_ssize_t index   
    cdef FLOAT_TYPE_t dist_vec = 0.0 
    cdef FLOAT_TYPE_t v_min    = 0.0           
    cdef np.ndarray[ DTYPE_t, ndim=1 ] zeros_res = np.zeros( ( total_elements, )  , dtype = DTYPE )
    cdef np.ndarray[ DTYPE_t, ndim=1 ] result    
    cdef np.ndarray[ FLOAT_TYPE_t, ndim=1 ] v    
    cdef np.ndarray[ Py_ssize_t, ndim=2 ] z
    
    if ( np.abs( shift_value ) > w_max  ):         
        return  zeros_res
    else:        
        if ( shift_value != 0.0 ):            
            
            if shift_value > 0:                
                dist_vec = min( w_grid + shift_value ) 
                v        = np.abs( w_grid - dist_vec  )
                v_min    = v.min() 
                z        = np.argwhere( v == v_min ) 
                index    = z[0][0]
                result   = np.roll( the_array, index )
                result[0:index] = 0                 
            else:
                dist_vec = max( w_grid + shift_value ) 
                v        = np.abs( w_grid - dist_vec  )
                v_min    = v.min() 
                z        = np.argwhere( v == v_min )
                index    = total_elements - z[0][0]                
                result   = np.roll( the_array, -index )
                result[-index:] = 0                                                   
            return  result                    
        else: return the_array
```

I observe no improve of performance in Cython, it even goes a bit slower. I have read this typically has to do with incorrect typings, but looking at the code I don't see any types declarations missing. What am I doing wrong here? Also, if someone suggests a better way to perform the shifting I would be very happy to hear, many thanks!

Comment: Haven't used cython for quite some time, but does `cdef` or `cpdef` for the function help?

Comment: I cannot use cdef because I want to call the function from the main program, which is .py like. Using cpdef does not solve the issue, I just tried compiling again and it still gives the same performance.

Comment: And you are sure that this function is the performance bottleneck? Could it be that the computations just take that long in numpy or that you have lots of iterations in pure python?

Comment: The function is not the performance bottleneck, but indeed it's called many times on iterations in pure python. Nevertheless, I would like to understand what is going on here and where the error comes from, basically one should expect single call improvement of the routine in Cython with respect to Python, mostly considering this is a very simple routine.

Comment: The reason that the cython code offers minimal speed benefits here is that it keeps calling into python functions within the numpy library. Those are not optimized as c function calls. Ideally cython provides the best performance benefit when you iterate over the item elements itself rather than vectorize (as would be the pythonic/numpy way).

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Making the function `cdef` or `cpdef` reduces the overhead of the function call, but the speed of the code within the function remains the same. I doubt it would have much value here.